# Session Expired Issue for IE browser in FBA Web Application

Tags: 2010, forms-authentication, central-administration

we have extend session timeout with the help of couple of posts :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147183%28v=office.14%29.aspx

http://jasear.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/sharepoint-2010-set-session-timout-on-a-fba-enabled-site/

after implement script still session timeout doesn't working on IE browser whenever i am checked on other browser(Mozilla) it is working as expected.